# How to download a jar file in corda?

Tags: corda

I have uploaded a jar file in a node.
How to download the attachment.
While downloading the attachment, will I get the attachment in jar file itself? There will be a download button in UI, on clicking the attachment need to download. In UI, I will provide hash of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `CordaRPCOps.openAttachment()` method. It takes as input the hash of the attachment, and returns an `InputStream` of the attachment JAR.

Here's a simple endpoint to download an attachment as an input stream:

```
@GET
@Path("download-attachment")
fun downloadAttachment(@QueryParam("attachment_hash") attachmentHash: String): InputStream {
    val secureHash = SecureHash.parse(attachmentHash)
    return rpcOps.openAttachment(secureHash)
}
```

You then need to write out the input stream as a JAR file. Here's a simple helper function to do that:

```
fun downloadJar(url: String) {
    val inputStream = URL(url).openStream()

    BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
        File("./downloaded_jar.jar").outputStream().use { outputStream ->
            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        }
    }
}
```